# L is not defined (Leaflet.js node package)

Tags: angular, typescript, leaflet

I am trying to get the example from the [Leaflet quickstart guide](https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/) to work in Angular 7, but the error `ERROR ReferenceError: L is not defined` appears. Note: I am not including Leaflet via JS files but installed it through npm via `npm install leaflet`, and it does show up in my `node_modules`.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
declare let L;


@Component({
  selector: 'app-mapvisual',
  templateUrl: './mapvisual.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mapvisual.component.css']
})
export class MapvisualComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      attribution: '© <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org    /copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(map);
  }
}
```

*EDIT:* I found the solution [here.](https://github.com/Asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet)

Comment: Your issue was with installing a library typings (`@types/leaflet` in this case) and then using them (`import L from 'leaflet'`, which imports both the package and typings).

Answer (score 1):

You must include these resources in your index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.css"
    integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ=="
    crossorigin=""/>

    <!-- Make sure you put this AFTER Leaflet's CSS -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.js"
    integrity="sha512-GffPMF3RvMeYyc1LWMHtK8EbPv0iNZ8/oTtHPx9/cc2ILxQ+u905qIwdpULaqDkyBKgOaB57QTMg7ztg8Jm2Og=="
    crossorigin=""></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

in your component.html file

```html
 <div id="mapid"></div>
```

component.css

```css
#mapid { height: 180px; }
```

in your component.ts file

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
declare let L;


@Component({
  selector: 'app-mapvisual',
  templateUrl: './mapvisual.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mapvisual.component.css']
})
export class MapvisualComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const map = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      attribution: '© <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org    /copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(map);
  }
}
```

Comment: I just found that I only had to follow this link and all the information is actually right here: https://github.com/Asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet It's a shame that this information is not on the official page or on the npm package page.

Comment: I did, but since it did not answer my question, I won't accept it. Thanks a lot for the help, though!